# Use gnome-terminal and tmux together: how to launch with the most recent working directory?

Tags: linux, gnome, tmux, gnome-terminal

I'm currently using gnome-terminal and tmux together: every time I start gnome-terminal, a tmux is started:

```
#!/bin/bash

args=()
if type tmux > /dev/null; then
  args+=('-e' "tmux new-session")
fi

exec gnome-terminal "${args[@]}" "$@"
```

But how can I start tmux with the working dir of the most recently active tmux session if there is one existing active tmux session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might help is the `list-panes` command which you can use with `-a` for all.  By default it does not provide what you want, but you can give it a format and in that include, for example, the `pane_current_path`, and perhaps enough other values for you to decide which of the panes you want to copy. Eg

```
$ tmux list-panes -a -F 'uniq=#D pane=#P title="#T" sess=#S windex=#I winnam=#W activ=#{pane_active} pwd=#{pane_current_path}'
uniq=%0 pane=0 title="myhost 2" sess=0 windex=0 winnam=bash activ=0 pwd=/home/meuh
uniq=%1 pane=1 title="myhost 3" sess=0 windex=0 winnam=bash activ=1 pwd=/home/meuh
uniq=%2 pane=0 title="myhost 4" sess=1 windex=0 winnam=bash activ=0 pwd=/tmp
uniq=%4 pane=1 title="myhost 5" sess=1 windex=0 winnam=bash activ=1 pwd=/usr/lib
uniq=%3 pane=0 title="myhost 1" sess=2 windex=0 winnam=bash activ=1 pwd=/tmp
```

The meaning of each variable eg `#D` for *unique pane id* is described in the man page under FORMATS. You might choose the largest of these ids as the most recent pane, and the `pwd=` value as the desired directory. Eg pipe the above tmux command into

```
 | awk '{id=substr($1,7)+0;if(id>max){max=id;pwd=$NF}} END{print substr(pwd,5)}'
```

---

Using the `window_activity` variable in later tmuxes, which gives the time in seconds since the epoch of last activity in the window, you can simplify the above to listing just this value and the current path, and taking the path for the maximum activity value:

```
tmux list-panes -a -F '#{window_activity} #{pane_current_path}' |
awk '{time=$1+0;if(time>max){max=time;pwd=substr($0,length($1)+2)}} END{print pwd}'
```

Comment: Thank you! I suggest to use session with the largest `window_activity` as the last used session. Do you agree? Can we put it into the answer?

Comment: My tmux doesn't have a `window_activity` variable. Do you mean `window_activity_flag` or `window_active`? Both of these are only 0 or 1, so there may be many panes that have the same value.

Comment: It is available on 2.3 at least: 
"window_activity                 Integer time of window last activity"

Comment: That's a great solution. I don't have the newer tmux but I looked through its man page and updated my answer. Thanks.